# How to delay synchronization of values of binding in JavaFX?

Tags: java, binding, javafx-2

I am learning JavaFX and impressed by its binding model.

Is it possible in JavaFX to bind property of domain class to textProperty of TextField and have this binding to bind values(make them equal) after Button is pressed.

So, I want to bind my StringProperty to textProperty of TextField and both properties should be really synchronised only once after user clicked OK button and as a result of change of my StringProperty, its ChangeListener is called.

So far I see that whenever property textProperty is changed my bound StringProperty is changed too, and I want to delay(postpone) this synchronization till OK button is pressed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No direct way (API) exists.

Use value propogation into the event handler of button press action (onActionEvent), with code like textField.setText(stringProperty.getValue()); and don't use binding.

Comment: This is what I am using actually.Thanks!